# findElement By XPath not supported in Selenium VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
variableName = driver.findElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='T_F2']/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[4]/span[2]"))
```

Running the above always seems to lead to the error:

[image]

Why is this? I always see other people using findElement By XPath. If it helps, I generated about half of my code using Selenium's 'record' feature. I then converted the code into 'VBA/Webdriver' before pasting it into Excel to use as a Macro.

What exactly is wrong with my code? I have used findElement a number of times before, so I'd have to guess that the problem is with the `By.XPath` part of my code... Is there any way around this?

Edit: Even `variableName = driver.findElementsByXPath(".//*[@id='T_F2']/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[4]/span[2]")` leads to the error 'Invalid procedure call or argument' even though it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
variableName = driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@id='T_F2']/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[4]/span[2]")
```

Notice that I removed the `.` in the beginning of the xPath and replaced `*` with `div`. Also, you're missing something at the end. You are just declaring the path here and not really getting a value.

EDIT: Referring to just the xPath is not usually enough. Do you want to perform an action on it, get the text inside, the tagname, etc.?

EDIT2: Testing to get the `.Text` attribute returns a "findElement By XPath not supported in Selenium VBA?" message.

Comment: The first leads to invalid procedure or call, and the second object does not support this property or method... I'm going to edit in my full code in a second just in case something else is causing this.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it... Is my code assigning a element to the variable rather than what I want, which is the text it contains?

Comment: @JimmyK: Exactly. Your declaration, which I failed to point out earlier, is incomplete. It's like pointing at an address of a house and not saying what you want from the house. As an example, use the edited code above (`.findElementByXPath...`) and add `.TagName` to the end. It should return the most immediate tag for your element, which is `span`.

Comment: Ahah! That makes sense. I managed to grab what I need using `.Text`. Thanks a lot for the help! I was also wondering if you could help me with one more thing. Now the modified code is causing `.Set Str` to complain about how the object doesn't support this property or method, but it shouldn't be complaining should it?

Comment: Hello, @JimmyK. Do you mean the `.SetText` in the Clipboard macro? Try using `CopyText variablename`, without the `()`. Without going to too much detail that I might get wrong, the `()` is often used when you have to assign the function to a variable. For instance, `Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("Aha")`. However, if it's just a normal call to open `Aha`, `Workbooks.Open "Aha"` will suffice. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me:

```
Dim variableName() as variant

variableName = driver.findElementsByXPath("//div[@id='T_F2']/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[4]/span[2]").getdata
```

Notice it's "find elements [plural] by XPath". This creates a two-dimensional array. variableName(1,1) will have the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(I know it's been more than 6 years, but it's my first contribution and I can't resist! Maybe that can help someone else)

You have to initialise the following:

```
Dim By As New By, variableName As WebElement
```

and because *variableName* is an object, it has to be declared, as follows:

```
Set variableName = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//*[@id='T_F2']/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[4]/span[2]"))
```